# Java adding contents of 2 different sized int arrays

Tags: java, arrays, biginteger

I need help with creating a VeryLargeInteger class similar to the BigInteger however, as part of my assignment I am not allowed to use BigInteger. I have started off by storing large numbers as strings and then converting them to int[] to perform mathematical functions with them. The problem I am running into is working with two different sized arrays such as:

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}  // represents 12,345
int[] b = {1, 2, 4}       //represents 124
```

When I add them I get:

```
int[] c = {2, 4, 7, 4, 5}
```

instead of

```
int[] c = {1, 2, 4, 6, 9}
```

This is a little messy.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class VeryLargeInteger
{
    int[] test, test2;
    String temp, temp2;
    int size;
    VeryLargeInteger(int[] input)
    {
        int[] test = input;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
    }
    VeryLargeInteger(long input1)
    {
        long input = input1;
        temp = Long.toString(input1);
        test = convert(temp);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
    }
    VeryLargeInteger(String input1)
    {
        temp = input1;
        test = convert(input1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
    }
    public static int[] convert(String input)
    {
        int [] array = new int[input.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        {
            int value = input.charAt(i) - '0';
            array[i] = value;
        }
        return array;
    }
    VeryLargeInteger add(VeryLargeInteger other)
    {
        int max = Math.max(this.temp.length(), other.temp.length());
      int[] result = new int[max];
      int carry = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
    {

        int a = i < this.test[i] ? this.test[this.test[i] - i -1] : 0;
        int b = i < other.test[i] ? other.test[other.test[i] - i -1] : 0;
        int sum = a + b + carry;
        carry = sum / 10;
        sum -= carry;
        result[result.length - i - 1] = sum;
    }
    VeryLargeInteger added = new VeryLargeInteger(result);
    return added;
    }
    /*
    VeryLargeInteger sub(VeryLargeInteger other)
    {

    }
    VeryLargeInteger mul(VeryLargeInteger other)
    {

    }
    VeryLargeInteger div(VeryLargeInteger other)
    {

    }
    VeryLargeInteger mod(VeryLargeInteger other)
    {

    }
    static String toString(VeryLargeInteger other)
    {

    }*/
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        VeryLargeInteger a = new VeryLargeInteger(1050L);
        VeryLargeInteger b = new VeryLargeInteger("121123");
        VeryLargeInteger c = a.add(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll find all your arithmetic operations much easier if you store your arrays in increasing order of place value, not decreasing.  For example, use `{ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 }` to store 12345.

Comment: (Pay attention to David's comment above: the proposed reversal makes it easy to check for the "ends" of the numbers when iterating the math ops such that no fictitious "leading 0" has to be stored.)

Comment: You will also need to check that the sum of the two digits aren't > 9, otherwise you will have to keep a carry.

Comment: As part of the assignment I have to be able to input long values as well as Strings (for indefinitely large numbers).

Comment: And with the code above, you need to add 1 to `size` before you start, otherwise you'll get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if you try to work out `5 + 5`.

Answer (score 0):

You could pad the second array to get them to add properly:

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] b = {0, 0, 1, 2, 4};
```

Then, if your add method compares `a[0]` to `b[0]` and so forth, you will get `{1, 2, 4, 6, 9}`.

Answer (score 0):

**An important note I would like to make is this:** You are not using the benefit of integers. Integers are 32 bits long, which are 32 digits in base 2. Now, you are using an integers as 1 digit in base 10. By doing this, you are only using 0.0000002% of the memory in a useful way. Use the full range that integers support. The point would be to make an array of integers, but where each integer effectively represents 32 bits of the actual number you want to hold. Adding them together then just goes component-wise, and take care of overflow by using a carry.

**To fix the problem as you are facing it now:** Align your arrays right. Do not add leading zeroes as *Mike Koch* suggests, but align them properly, by basically accessing the array elements from back to front, instead of from front to back, as you are doing now. By looking at your code, you have attempted that, but you are having trouble with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions I guess. Access both components of the array like this:

```
int[] number0 = ...;
int[] number1 = ...;
int max = Math.max(number0.length + number1.length) + 1;
int[] result = new int[max];

int carry = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
{
    int c0 = i < number0.length ? number0[number0.length - i - 1] : 0;
    int c1 = i < number1.length ? number1[number1.length - i - 1] : 0;

    int sum = c0 + c1 + carry;
    carry = sum / 10;
    sum -= carry;

    result[result.length - i - 1] = sum;
}
```

Comment: So maybe add a method to reverse input, add zeroes to the end to re-size the smaller array, and then flip it back around to perform mathematical functions to it?

Comment: @Trent No.  Just don't.

Comment: I wrote some code that would do the job. I haven't tested it, and you still have to figure out the correct value of `max`. I think that would be something like: `Math.max(number0.length + number1.length) + 1`.

Comment: Hmm, I am unfamiliar with how you wrote some of that out.                 `int c0 = i < number0.length ? number0[number0.length - i - 1] : 0;`     What is this bit of code doing?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux I think you want `sum -= carry * 10;` instead of `sum -= carry;` or alternatively omit that line altogether and just use `sum % 10` on the bottom line.

Comment: I edited my code to use this, however now I am getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on this bit of code `int a = i < this.test[i] ? this.test[this.test[i] - i -1] : 0;`.

Comment: `Math.max()` takes two values, not an expression. Try: `Math.max(number0.length, number1.length);`. This will return the size of the largest of the two arrays. You don't need to add one to them, because `length` is not a zero-based operation. It starts counting at 1. You're probably getting the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because of it.

Comment: Can anyone tell me where to find more information about how this bit of code works? `int c0 = i < number0.length ? number0[number0.length - i - 1] : 0;`

Comment: @Trent look up "ternary operator".